# ¿porque laravel al momento de subir un archivo me redirecciona al login?

Tags: laravel, post, login

se desea subir un archivo y traerme los datos de el mismo pero al momento de presionar el boton de subir me redirecciona al login ya revise los middleware de sesion pero ahi no esta el problema, pero no solo es ahi, cuando intento acceder a una ruta por post es cuando pasa eso, estoy usando laravel 5.4

Estas imagenes muestran el codigo del controlador para subir el archivo, la vista para subir el archivo y las rutas

Controller:

```
public function getRepxdia(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $content = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());

    if ($content == true) {
        $sustitut[] = $content;
        foreach ($sustitut as $sustituto => $conteiner):
            $rows = explode("\n", $conteiner);
            unset($rows[0]);
            foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
                $value = explode("|", $value);
                $datas[] = $value;
            } 
        endforeach;
       return $datas;

    }
    else{   return back()->with('notification','No se pudo cargar el archivo!'); }

}
```

Vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y archivo web:

```
 <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('template');
});

/*--------------------------------------- LOGIN Y REGISTRO ---------------------------------------------------------*/
Route::get('/registro', 'RegistroController@index');
Route::post('/registro', 'RegistroController@register');
//Route::match(['GET','POST'], '/registro', 'RegistroController@register');

Route::get('/login', 'SignController@index');
Route::post('/login', 'SignController@login');
Route::post('/logout', ['as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>'SignController@logout']);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'check'], function(){
    Route::get('/home', 'InicioController@index');

    //------------------------------- Ver datos REPXDIA ------------------------
    Route::get('/data', 'InicioController@index');

    //------------------------ Cargar archivo REPXDIA --------------------------
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'rol'], function(){

        //----------------------- Procesar y Validar Datos de Archivo ----------
        Route::get('/file', 'FileController@index');
        Route::post('/upfile', 'FileController@getRepxdia');
        Route::match(['GET','POST'], '/datos/modify', 'FileController@datos');

        //----------------------------------- ADMINISTAR A LOS USUARIOS ---------------------
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
            Route::get('/admin/users', 'UsersController@index');

            //---------------------------- Agregar a un USUARIO --------------------
            Route::get('/admin/adduser', 'UsersController@form');
            Route::post('/admin/adduser', 'UsersController@add');

            //---------------------------- Editar a un USUARIO ---------------------
            //Route::get('/admin/edituser/{id}', ['as' => 'bring.user', 'suicide'])

        });
    });
});
//Route::get('/home', 'InicioController@index');
```

Si necesitan ver mas codigo diganme y de que les gustaria que pusiera el codigo, no sabia muy bien que tanto o de que poner codigo, muchas gracias por su atencion!

Comment: Y tu Código? vendría bien colocar el código así alguno puede ayudarte

Comment: Sin código no tendremos la más mínima idea.